How to fix DistributionNotFound error when building a Jupyter Book?
When I try to build a Jupyter Book, I get this error:
Running Sphinx v7.2.6
[etoc] Changing master_doc to 'intro'
loading pickled environment... failed: source directory has changed
failed

Exception occurred:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'dataclasses; python_version < "3.7"' distribution was not found and is required by the application

I created a virtual environment with Python3.8 instead of Python3.10 in case that was part of the issue, and it still gave me the same error. I used:
mamba create -n miseq python=3.8
mamba activate miseq
pip install jupyter
pip install jupyter-book
jupyter-book build .

I also tried creating a kernel for the Jupyter Notebook with a different version of Python and that didn't work either.
